# Why is Visual Basic saying m path name is illegal

Tags: vb.net

I am using this specific line of code in Visual Basic, when I run the program it always crashes at this line saying that the "Empty path name is not legal". I have created this file in the resources part of the project section.

```
Dim Reader as StreamReader = New StreamReader(My.Resources.TextData)
```

If you could tell me how to solve this problem or suggest a new way to write to and read the file saved in my resources folder.

Comment: Who told you that `My.Resources` was a folder?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Ok it may not be a "folder" but you still know what I mean

Comment: Why would you stream a file included in the resources of your project? I don't get what you're doing here. Did you mean to add a path to a file in the project Settings and then reference the path that way?

Comment: What's in the resource you are trying to read?

Answer (score 1):

To read files in the 'resource folder' of your project, just declare a string to the saved resource

Example:

```
Dim Reader As String = My.Resources.TextData
TextBox1.Text = Reader
```

You cannot write to resource files while running. As file in the my.resources are read-only.

I suggest you use My.Settings instead: Go to **My Project -> Settings** and assign a Name to the setting.

To read a setting with My.Settings, use this code:

```
Dim readSetting As String = My.Settings.ExampleString1
TextBox1.Text = readSetting
```

To write to a setting with My.Settings, use this code:

```
My.Settings.ExampleString1 = "Enter your text here"
```

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) the stream reader that takes a string as a parameter expect a path with filename as seen in [the example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy(v=vs.110).aspx). Put a breakpoint and look at the content of the resource. If it's not a filename then you are looking at [doing something else](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).